# Setting up local FTP that can easily be accessed by multiple users

Tags: networking, ftp, dropbox

*This is a cross-post from Superuser where I was unintentionally off-topic*

We are a small office which deal with large amounts of sensitive customer files. Recently our governing body restricted use of cloud services such as Dropbox, Google Drive, etc. I have been tasked with finding an alternative solution and am coming across some issues that I would greatly appreciate some help with.

I ordered a static IP from my ISP and connected a hard drive to the router. What I currently have set up is that someone at their home office can log in to ftp://207.XXX.XXX.125 (X's are actual numbers obviously), log in with username/password, and access the files via FTP through my router. This works for being able to access the files remotely, however there are some quality of life problems for people who are used to Dropbox.

For instance, if you have the Windows Explorer open to the FTP (it connects through "The Internet/207.XXX.XXX.125/All/Filepath") and drags a file into Gmail, all that gets dropped there is the filepath instead of the pdf. Windows also seems to run into issues remembering where the file path is so the users have to constantly plug in ftp://207..... in order to access files.

Perhaps you can help me with a solution. Ideally I am looking for local document storage which can easily be accesssed by Windows or Mac by utilizing my office Static IP.

I've done a ton of research but I feel like I'm just banging my head against the wall constantly. We have no problem throwing some money at the problem as long as we have control over our files, it is secure, and some QOL adjustments are met.

Thanks!

Dylan

Answer (score 2):

I don't have 50+ reputation points; otherwise, I would ask for some clarification in a comment.  Also, I need more than 10 reputation points to post more than two links.

By the title, I got the impression that you were looking for FTP *server* software but, reading the description, it sounds like you are all set on the server end, though I might suggest buying a domain to make access a little friendlier than using an IP address, or even just using a cheap/free host name service, like [No-IP](https://www.noip.com/).

On the client end, I've never had great experience using either Windows Explorer or any of the major we browsers (IE, Firefox, Chrome, etc.) as an FTP client.  Two dedicated FTP clients that come to mind are: [FileZilla](https://filezilla-project.org/) and [WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/download.php).  With WinSCP, you can create a desktop shortcut that opens the program and creates a connection to a specific FTP server, and even open the local and remote sides of the UI to specific paths (perhaps FileZilla can do all that too).  They both have a "Commander" style UI, which is a vertically split, local-and-remote layout.  You can drag-n-drop within, from within to outside or from outside to within.

Adding more links, now that I can. :)

[image]

Comment: +1 Please feel free to edit answer to include links etc, you got over that barrier now:) Also note, you can comment below your post, and OP will get notified